# Android Wrap_Content

Tags: java, android

When I add a button and set the Layout_Width, Layout_Height to Wrap_Content. What am I referring to because when I do that. Also, I see a box expand to fit the content. What is that box? I know that box is not the layout because my relative layout is set to fit parents. So what is the container that hold the button and allows me to modified the layout of that container?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap_Content will take as much space as required by the element, it has setted height and width for.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I still don't understand What is Wrapping the content? and what is the content of a button?

Comment: WRAP_CONTENT, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).Content is basically the data that your view is holding.

Comment: So if I have the button what would be the view and what would be the content?

Answer (score 0):

`wrap_content` simply means that it'll wrap the content whatever may it be. In your case, the content would be the text in Button.

For example, if you have a button with text `Click Me`, then it'll take only the space required to fit the text `Click me` into the button box.

If you increase the text size, the button will automatically increase to fit the text in it.